# Excel-Vba: select first cell with no value based on the code below

Tags: vba, excel

With the macro below, I managed to select all of the cells in column B with a value. But now I need to change that code so that it selects the cell just underneath the cells with a value.

**Example:**
Let's say the macro below selects cells B8:B15, then it should select cell B16 with the new code. What should I add to this code to make this work?

```
Sheets("sheet1").Select

Dim LR2 As Long, cell2 As Range, rng2 As Range
With Sheets("sheet1")
    LR2 = .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For Each cell2 In .Range("B8:B" & LR2)
        If cell2.Value <> "" Then
            If rng2 Is Nothing Then
                Set rng2 = cell2
            Else
                Set rng2 = Union(rng2, cell2)
            End If
        End If
    Next cell2
    rng2.Select
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Offset` method of the Range object should be what you are looking for.

On any range, you can do something like:

```
newRang=rng.offset(1,0)
```

see these resources to learn more:

- [MSDN Library: Range Object (Excel)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238(v=office.15).aspx)
- [MSDN Library: Range.Offset property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840060(v=office.15).aspx)
- [MSDN Library: Devlopers Guide to the Excel Range Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg192736(v=office.14).aspx)
- [TechOnTheNet: Excel Range](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/offset.php)

Comment: I tried your method but it didn't work. Instead of selecting cells B8:B15, it now selects B9:B16 while it should only select cell B16. Any idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work

```
Sheets("sheet1").Select


Dim LR2 As Long, cell2 As Range, rng2 As Range
With Sheets("sheet1")
    LR2 = .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For Each cell2 In .Range("B8:B" & LR2)
        If cell2.Value <> "" Then
            If rng2 Is Nothing Then
                Set rng2 = Sheets("sheet1").cells(cell2.Row + 1, cell2.Column)
            Else
                Set rng2 = Union(rng2, cell2)
            End If
        End If
    Next cell2
    rng2.Select
End With
```